# A quicker route to $\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\b{\beta}\lim_{\b\to0} \frac{2(\o-\cos\b)-\b\sin\b}{2(\o-\cos\b)\b^2}$

Tags: limits, derivatives

I encountered this limit while calculating the $\varphi$ function for a $3\times 3$ skew-symmetric matrix
$${
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\b{\beta}\lim_{\b\to0} \frac{2(\o-\cos\b)-\b\sin\b}{2(\o-\cos\b)\b^2} = \frac{\o}{12} \\
}$$
The interesting part is that it took **four** applications of L'Hospital's Rule to resolve the limit.

My question is: Are there any trigonometric identities that can reduce the number of derivatives that are required?

Comment: Are you allowed to use Taylor expansion?

Comment: That would be fine.

Comment: @greg, please read my answer and tell me if you like it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand{\b}{\beta}$
Using the expansions of the cosine and sine functions, you have:
$$2(1-\cos \b)-\b \sin \b \sim 2\left(\frac{\b^2}2-\frac{\b^4}{24}\right)-\b \left(\b-\frac{\b^3}6\right)=\frac{\b^4}{12}\\
2(1-\cos \b)\b^2\sim \b^4$$

Hence
$$\frac{2(1-\cos \b)-\b \sin \b}{2(1-\cos \b)\b^2}\sim \frac{\b^4/12} {\b^4}\to\frac1{12}$$

Comment: wow. really like this.

Comment: @nicwen Taylor expansion is the most powerful tool to compute limits

Comment: You reduced the derivative count all the way to zero. Can't do much better than that.

Comment: @greg, actually the derivatives are in the coefficients of the expansions of sine and cosine. In fact, if $f(x)=\cos x$, then $\cos x=f(x)=f(0)+f’(0)x+\frac{f’’(0)}2x^2+\frac{f’’’(0)}{3!}x^3+\frac{f^{IV}(0)}{4!}x^4+\ldots=1-\frac12x^2+\frac1{24}x^4+\ldots$

Answer (score 2):

We can use the following notable limit :

$\lim\limits_{\beta\to0}\dfrac{1-\cos\beta}{\beta^2}=\dfrac12\;.\quad\color{blue}{(1)}$

By using L'Hospital's rule just one time, we can calculate the following limits:

$\lim\limits_{\beta\to0}\dfrac{\beta-\sin\beta}{\beta^3}=\lim\limits_{\beta\to0}\dfrac{1-\cos\beta}{3\beta^2}=\dfrac16\;\;,\quad\color{blue}{(2)}$

$\lim\limits_{\beta\to0}\dfrac{\cos\beta-1+\frac12\beta^2}{\beta^4}=\lim\limits_{\beta\to0}\dfrac{\beta-\sin\beta}{4\beta^3}=\dfrac1{24}\;.\quad\color{blue}{(3)}$

Now we will calculate the OP’s limit by using the results $\,(1)\,,\,(2)\,$ and $\,(3)\,:$

$\lim\limits_{\beta\to0}\dfrac{2(1-\cos\beta)-\beta\sin\beta}{2(1-\cos\beta)\beta^2}=$

$=\lim\limits_{\beta\to0}\dfrac{2\left(1-\cos\beta-\frac12\beta^2\right)+\beta\left(\beta-\sin\beta\right)}{2\left(\!\frac{1-\cos\beta}{\beta^2}\!\right)\beta^4}=$

$=\lim\limits_{\beta\to0}\dfrac1{2\left(\!\frac{1-\cos\beta}{\beta^2}\!\right)}\left[\dfrac{-2\left(\cos\beta-1+\frac12\beta^2\right)}{\beta^4}+\dfrac{\beta-\sin\beta}{\beta^3}\right]=$

$=\dfrac1{2\!\cdot\!\frac12}\left[-2\!\cdot\!\dfrac1{24}+\dfrac16\right]=-\dfrac1{12}+\dfrac16=\dfrac1{12}\;.$

Comment: $+\tt1$ Yes, something like this. Substituting $\alpha=\large{\frac{\beta}{2}}\,$ I'm able to obtain the limit with 2 iterations of l'Hospital.

Answer (score 1):

Let us first replace the variable $\beta$ by $x$ to reduce typing effort here. Since $(1-\cos x) /x^2\to 1/2$ as $x\to 0$ the limit in question is equal to the limit of the expression $$\frac {2(1-\cos x) - x\sin x} {x^4}$$ Putting $x=2t$ and using trigonometric identities $$\cos 2t=1-2\sin^2t,\sin 2t=2\sin t\cos t$$ the desired limit is $$\frac{1}{4}\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin t-t\cos t} {t^3}\cdot\frac{\sin t} {t} $$ which is same as $$\frac{1}{4}\lim_{t\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin t - t} {t^3}+\frac{1-\cos t} {t^2}\right)$$ The limit of first fraction requires L'Hospital's rule or Taylor expansions and we then have the desired limit as $$\frac{1}{4}\left(-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{2}\right) =\frac{1}{12}$$ I prefer a bit of algebraic manipulation so as to minimize the use of L'Hospital's rule.